# Ratchet - Could not get query string on server side

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

On client side:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8082/chat?id=123&tid=7');
```

On server side

```
class MyApp implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

        var_dump($conn->WebSocket->request->getQuery()); // I tried to access to query string here, but it did not work
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

...
}
```

Here is the dump result what I got from my console

```
class Guzzle\Http\QueryString#85 (5) {
  protected $fieldSeparator =>
  string(1) "&"
  protected $valueSeparator =>
  string(1) "="
  protected $urlEncode =>
  string(8) "RFC 3986"
  protected $aggregator =>
  NULL
  protected $data =>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I can't see any clue about the value of two query strings on my URL `id` and `tid`. 
Updated: I have tried to dump all in the variable `$request` on Http/Route to check, I can see the getQuery works, but how could I do same thing on the function onOpen?

```
 protected $url =>
 class Guzzle\Http\Url#67 (8) {
   protected $scheme =>
   string(4) "http"
   protected $host =>
   string(9) "localhost"
   protected $port =>
   int(8082)
   protected $username =>
   NULL
   protected $password =>
   NULL
   protected $path =>
   string(5) "/chat"
   protected $fragment =>
   NULL
   protected $query =>
   class Guzzle\Http\QueryString#66 (5) {
     protected $fieldSeparator =>
     string(1) "&"
     protected $valueSeparator =>
     string(1) "="
     protected $urlEncode =>
     string(8) "RFC 3986"
     protected $aggregator =>
     NULL
     protected $data =>
     array(3) {
       ...
     }
   }
 }
```

The message is transferred correctly between the client and server but the query strings.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really comprehend the following code in src\Ratchet\Http then I don't make sure whether it is a bug or not.

```
$parameters = array();

        foreach($route as $key => $value) {
            if ((is_string($key)) && ('_' !== substr($key, 0, 1))) {
                $parameters[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

 $url = Url::factory($request->getPath());
        $url->setQuery($parameters);
```

But I have modified as following:

```
$parameters = $request->getQuery();
```

My above line will override the iteration to set something into the `$params`. At least I can access to the query strings